# F5 Does Not Build on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Ok, classic "F5 Does Not Build on Visual Studio" question. Problem is, nothing suggested so far has worked for me. What I have tried so far:

1) Making sure that "Tools -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> On Run, when projects are out of date:" was set to "Always build".

2) Making sure that "Tools -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run" was unchecked.

3) Making sure that "Right click on solution -> Configuration Manager -> Build" was checked.

4) Also, I have tried opening up a new project but the problem persists. So, most probably problem is project/solution independent.

My Visual Studio is 2010 Ultimate, if that would make any difference.

Thank you very much for your concern in advance.

Comment: Did you check the Keyboard associations in Tools -> Options ->Environment -> KeyBoard -> Debug.Start?

Comment: Shortcuts for selected command: F5 (Global)